# String not removable in a JTextPane

Tags: java, swing

I append a `String` in a `JTextPane` now I want to make it not removable. This `String` is added automatically to the `JTextPane` with an action listener of a button. Can somebody explain me how to do it? Thanks

Comment: How would it be removed?

Comment: I am not trying to remove it but make it not removable ( not editable). And append a text or modify the text above the string

Comment: That is why I am asking, "how would it be removed". You can 'setEditable(false)` and a user couldn't change the text. Also, it would help to create a small example that demonstrates what you mean. Maybe just a JTextPane on a JFrame with a button to set the text.

Comment: It can be removed with backspace. And i want that when it is appended to the jtexpane the user should not be able to remove it anymore with backspace and rhe string should stay static

Comment: So far, with your criteria, setEditable(false) would suffice. Do you not want your user to be able to edit any of the text before the text you inserted, or just the text that was inserted?

Comment: I want to make the string not editable and be able to modify the text before the string and after the string

Comment: See [Protected Text Component](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/21/protected-text-component/)